# Java game Mouse input on buttons not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to make mouse input work in my Java game, but i can't seem to figure it out. I want to click where i made my button and it should change my State from End to Game and respawn my player and my bullet enemies. Why does the following code not change my State to Game instead of End?

My End Class

```
package BullHellSpel;

 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.util.Random;

 import BullHellSpel.Game.STATE;

 public class End extends MouseAdapter{

private Game game;
private Handler handler;
private HUD hud;
private Random r = new Random();


public End(Game game, Handler handler, HUD hud){
    this.game = game;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.hud = hud;
}



public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();

    if(game.gameState == STATE.End){
    if(mouseOver(mx, my, 75, 100, 200, 70)){
        game.gameState = STATE.Game; 
        handler.addObject(new Player(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT, ID.player, handler));
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        handler.addObject(new Bullet(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH), -1, ID.bullet, handler));
    }
}
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

}

private boolean mouseOver(int mx, int my, int x, int y, int width, int height){
    if(mx < x && mx > x + width){
        if(my < y && my > y + height){
            return true;        
        }else return false;
    }else return false;
}

public void tick() {


}

public void render(Graphics g) {

        Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 20);
        Font fnt1 = new Font("arial", 1, 16);
        g.setColor(Color.white);

        g.setFont(fnt);
        g.drawString("You lost with a score of: " + hud.getScore(), 40, 50);

        g.setFont(fnt1);
        g.drawRect(75, 100, 200, 70);
        g.drawString("Retry Game", 90, 140);

        g.drawRect(75, 215, 200, 70);
        g.drawString("Quit Game", 90, 255);
    }


 }
```

In my game Class:

```
 package BullHellSpel;

 import java.awt.Canvas;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import sun.applet.Main;
 import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Random;





 public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 360, HEIGHT = 640 / 1;
private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;


private Random r;
private Handler handler;
private HUD hud;
private Spawn spawner;
private End end;
private Menu menu;


public enum STATE {
    End,
    Menu,
    Game;

};

public STATE gameState = STATE.Game; 

public Game(){




    handler = new Handler();
    hud = new HUD();
    end = new End(this, handler, hud);
    menu = new Menu(this, handler, hud);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
    this.addMouseListener(end);
    this.addMouseListener(menu);

    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Space dodgers", this);


    spawner = new Spawn(handler, hud);
    r = new Random();


    if(gameState == STATE.Game){
        handler.addObject(new Player(r.nextInt(WIDTH), r.nextInt(HEIGHT), ID.player, handler));
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        handler.addObject(new Bullet(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH), -1, ID.bullet, handler));
    }
}





public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    try{
        thread.join();
        running = false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

public void run()
{

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;

    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running)
    {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;
                while(delta >=1)
                        {
                            tick();
                            delta--;
                        }
                        if(running)
                            render();
                        frames++;

                        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
                        {
                            timer += 1000;
                            System.out.println("FPS: "+ frames);
                            frames = 0;
                        }
    }
            stop();
}

private void tick(){
    handler.tick();
    if(gameState == STATE.Game)
    {
        hud.tick();
        spawner.tick();

        if(HUD.HEALTH <= 0){
            HUD.HEALTH = 100;
            handler.object.clear();
            gameState = STATE.End;

        }   
    }else if(gameState == STATE.End){
        end.tick();
    }else if(gameState == STATE.Menu){
        menu.tick();
    }

}
private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    //HIER KAN JE SHIT TEKENEN
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    //g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);




    handler.render(g);

    if(gameState == STATE.Game)
    {
    hud.render(g);
    }else if(gameState == STATE.End){
        end.render(g);
    }else if(gameState == STATE.Menu){
        menu.render(g);
    }

            g.dispose();
            bs.show();
}

public static int clamp(int var, int min, int max){
    if(var >= max)
        return var = max;
    else if(var <= min)
        return var = min;
    else
    return var;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Game();

}



 }
```

Comment: Your mouse logic only does something if your game state is END, that looks a bit weird to me

Comment: Just removed that line, still doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestion though ;)